# Hover on child div add a shadow on parent div

Tags: html, css, hover

What I am doing is, When I hover on my text then I have to show the shadow on parent div.
I tried below code and it's working but if I remove hover then my buttons are not clickable.

Because I used  `pointer-events: none;` to the parent div. Is there any other best way to hover on child div and shadow on parent div without `pointer-events: none;`? I have 4-5 buttons on my parent div.

```css
.box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
}

.box .child {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.box:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px -9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px -9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px -9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="child"><a href="">Hover me</a></div>
  <a href="" class="clickme">click me</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the shadow using a pseudo element:

```css
.box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  transform:translate(0); /* to make the fixed element relative to the parent */
}

.box .child {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}
.box .child::before {
  content:"";
  position:fixed; /* not absolute but fixed */
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.child:hover::before {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px -9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px -9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px -9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="child"><a href="">Hover me</a></div>
  <a href="" class="clickme">click me</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Give me some time to check this